# What does a two dimensional array followed by a parenthesis with two strings do?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

The code I am working on has a few lines similar to the format of this:

```
array[secondArray[0]][secondArray[2]]('string', 'otherString');
```

But I'm pretty confused as to what it does?
Does it set values of the two dimensional `array` at the positions given by 'secondArray' to the values of the strings?

Comment: Consider reading up on "square bracket notation".

Comment: We know `[]` means access a property by a string ID, and `something()` is calling a function. There doesn't seem to be much else.

Comment: Looks like the arrays hold function references and the `()` invoke the function with those parameters

Comment: That means that `array` is an array of arrays or an array of objects and that the value in `array[secondArray[0]][secondArray[2]]` is a function

Comment: If `array == [ [ 5, 6, function(arg) { /* ... */ } ] ]` then `array[0][2]("hello")` will call the function in the inner array with the parameter `"hello"`

Comment: Yes, thank you, you are all correct. I have never seen the syntax before but it looks like it does indeed pass the strings as functions parameters to functions in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we can surmise from what is shown is that you have function references in that array and the array is multidimensional

The `()` then invokes the function found at that array location determined by:

```
array[secondArray[0]][secondArray[2]]
```

The `secondArray` values would be integers that return the `array` indices needed to access those elements that hold the function references

---

A simplified example would be:

```js
function foo (str) {
    console.log('Foo called with arg:', str)
}

function bar (str) {
    console.log('Bar called with arg:', str)
}

// array of arrays that include function references
const arr =[[foo, 1, 2], [1, 2, bar]];

// invoke functions from array
arr[0][0]('Foo string');
arr[1][2]('Bar string');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually easy to understand what is going on by breaking down the code:

1. `secondArray[0]` retrieves the element at index 0 of `secondArray`. Let us call that element `elementAtIndex0`.
2. `secondArray[2]` retrieves the element at index 2 of `secondArray`. Let us call that element `elementAtIndex2`.
3. `array[elementAtIndex0]` retrieves the element at index `elementAtIndex0` of `array` which is a nested array. Let us call it `nestedArray`.
4. `array[elementAtIndex0][elementAtIndex2]` returns element at index `elementAtIndex2`of `nestedArray`  which is a function. And you invoke that function with arguments `'string'` and  `'otherString'`.

Look at the example below.

```js
const array = [
    23,
    [
        12,
        3,
        function (str1, str2) {
            return str1 + " " + str2;
        },
        23
    ]
];

const secondArray = [1, 0, 2, 3];

const elementAtIndex0 = secondArray[0];  // elementAtIndex0 = 1
const elementAtIndex2 = secondArray[2];  // elementAtIndex2 =  2
const string = array[elementAtIndex0][elementAtIndex2]("string", "otherString"); // string = "string otherString"
const sameString = array[secondArray[0]][secondArray[2]]('string', 'otherString'); //sameString = "string otherString"
```